# Как наложить rgba фон на картинку

Tags: css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.section__gallery {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.section__gallery-title {
  color: #01353E;
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.6px;
  padding-bottom: 212px;
  text-align: center;
}

.section__nav {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.section__navigation {
  padding-right: 20px;
  color: #242121;
  font-family: Roboto Condensed;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 18px;
  /* 75% */
  letter-spacing: 0.6px;
}

.section__navigation:hover {
  color: #00B2A0;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.section__photo {
  /* flex-wrap: nowrap; */
  padding-bottom: 73px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 1280px;
}

.section__photo-gallery {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.section__photo-gallery:hover {
  background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.70);
}
```

```html
ion class="section__gallery">
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="section__gallery-title">ГАЛЕРЕЯ<span>/</span></h2>
  <nav class="section__nav">
    <a class="section__navigation" href="">ВСЕ</a>
    <a class="section__navigation" href="">ТУРИСТЫ</a>
    <a class="section__navigation" href="">ПРИРОДА</a>
    <a class="section__navigation" href="">ПРОФИ</a>
  </nav>




  <div class="section__photo">
    <img class="section__photo-gallery" src="image/photo__bg-1.jpg" style="width: 42%; height: 258px;" alt="">
    <img class="section__photo-gallery" src="image/photo__bg-2.jpg" style="width: 266px" alt="">
    <img class="section__photo-gallery" src="image/photo__bg-3.jpg" style="width: 266px; height: 258px;" alt="">
    <img class="section__photo-gallery" src="image/photo__bg-4.jpg" style="width: 266px; height: 258px;" alt="">
    <img class="section__photo-gallery" src="image/photo__bg-5.jpg" style="width: 266px" alt="">
    <img class="section__photo-gallery" src="image/photo__bg-6.jpg" style="width: 42%; height: 258px;" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="section__btn">
    <a class="link__btn" href="">ПОКАЗАТЬ ЕЩЕ</a>
  </div>

</div>
</section>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `наложить rgba фон на картинку` как это понять? Переведи. (с)

Comment: Я скинул картинку с макета где на фото есть затемнение rgba, мне нужно сделать похожее на hover. У меня получается что rgba цвет появляется снизу и справа, я менял размер картинок так как оригинальный размер не помещается на мониторе.

Comment: У блока картинки позиция должная быть relative, в нем есть картинка и div, у div абсолютная позиция с высотой и длиной в 100%. У него и задавайте фон.

Comment: во первых обычно это делают через :before :after. во вторых его надо сделать. position: absolute поверх картинки, в третих стоит учесть что если в блкое есть паддинг его надо нивелировать